# Why Powerbuilder rebuild source 3 times in deploy?

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-2017

Recently we change our deploy server in my business. In the old server deploy take 1,5 hours but in the new one takes more than 4 hours (and in theory it is a more powerful computer). Looking the log of the deploy we see the problem is powerbuilder rebuild the source 3 times. We dont know why. If we move the source code again to the old server takes 1,5 hours again. So the problem is in configuration of powerbuilder in the new computer.

We are using PowerBuilder 2017 R3 1880

Comment: How many applications?  Do you have common libraries used in each?  Change from PBD to DLL compile?

Comment: @MattBalent Only one application... its big xD. Near 250 PBD. Its PBD compile. We cant change it to DLL because if we do it we need to modify the update software that we give to our clients.

Comment: Are you starting the build (deploy) via the project object painter, then Deploy menu item? Otherwise if a build script or ORCA script it may be set up to compile three times some people are religious about that, or could be a machine code compile which would be a lot of slow steps. We deal w same, server objects n-tier with PB 12.5

Comment: @RichBianco Yes I use deploy menu item in the project object. Although I was unaware of the possibility of making an ORCA script. I will investigate it. EDIT: I just saw that it is a separate program. I need to find another solution since I don't think my company is willing to buy the license.

Comment: For those considering ORCA script, the program is included with PowerBuilder. For versions 12.6 and below, it is my understanding that the script to perform the build must be on a machine licensed for PowerBuilder. PB 2017 and above by Appeon allows for a build machine that is not licensed which I'm not mentioning to spam/advertise, though it is one of many benefits to updating to Appeon PowerBuilder.

Comment: Perhaps PB did not ship with ORCAscript in some years but there is no separate license. If the build machine isn't licensed for PB than I don't think the ORCA script would work, this of course would be different for PB 2017 and above.

Comment: @RichBianco Yes the build machine have a PowerBuilder 2017 licence. I will investigate this method.